# How to tune inotify to use less memory?

Tags: linux, embedded

I'm working on an embedded linux system.

I tried to use inotify to monitor changes. But when I tried to monitor a huge numbers of folders (let's say more than 6000 folders), inotify uses a lot of memory (about 25-30MB). As you all know, 25-30MB in embedded system is considered to be large...

My questions are;

- is this normal?
- is anyone know how to tune this?
- any alternative to monitor a huge numbers of folders without adding watch in each folder?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know a recursive watch is not possible with an unpatched Linux kernel. See also https://superuser.com/questions/118642/recursive-filesystem-notifications-inotify-for-ubuntu-karmic-koala . Maybe *fanotify* would work for you, but it needs a kernel patch.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using [Auditd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html).

There is also a user space file system called [loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/), but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's inevitable to monitor directories recursively when using `inotify`.
reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify#Limitations

In order to improve `inotify(7)` performance(reduce memory usage, maybe), my suggestion is:
Whenever you start watching a directory, just focus on types of `inotify_event` that interest you(as less as possible), you can adjust the `mask` argument of `inotify_add_watch(2)` function to achieve this. Setting the `mask` argument value to `IN_ALL_EVENTS` to monitor all kinds to `inotify_event` is sometimes unnecessary.

Hope this helps.